# Make the console wait for correct input by user to close

Tags: java, console-application

I have a java console application which checks for password. If the password is correct then and only then the application window should close. Otherwise if it is incorrect password , the application window should not close until and unless the correct password is entered. I am not able to find any right java keywords which would close application window if the correct password is entered.

Comment: Code is better than English sometimes. You can [edit] your question to include some

Comment: When you ask a question on StackOverflow, is it is best if you "show your work." You should explain what you've tried so far. Bad question: "Please write some code for me that does X."

Answer (score 0):

Use [`System.exit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    while(true) {
        // get password
        if(passwordCorrect) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
import java.util.*;

public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

    String input = null;


    do{
        input = scn.nextLine();
        if(input == "password"){
            system.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```